# Speakers don't play sound after disconnecting and reconnecting monitor

Tags: audio, speakers, hardware-detection

I disconnected my desktop monitor from my tower and reconnected it to my work computer. Finished my work and reconnect my monitor to my desktop. But now I can't hear anything from my external speakers, both Youtube and Facebook (among others) are dead.

But if I go to the sound settings and then manage audio devices and test my speakers, they are definitely making distinctive test pings. I even placed my hands on both speakers and I can feel the test jingle as well as hear it. I have tried disabling and re-enabling the speakers in my sound settings. Still no luck!

Anyone have any idea what is going on?

Edit: Tried HDMI to see what would happen. No display or sound. I have tried using HDMI in the past with no trouble though.

Comment: Please post a answer to your  question

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it! In my sound settings I had speakers selected, when I really needed headphones selected. I don't know why it's categorizing my speakers as headphones but at least it works now. It was literally a two click fix! WTF lol